# Java - FileTransferClient - disconnect() = Connection reset

Tags: java, exception, ftp

I am not very skillfull with JAVA but unfortunatelly I need repair one application. I have already solved some problems but this problem is harder. I have tried find solution on forums but they are not very heplfull.

Long story short

```
.......
public FTPdownload(String _host, String _user, String _password) throws Exception {
        ftp = new FileTransferClient();
        ftp.setRemoteHost(_host);
        ftp.setUserName(_user);
        ftp.setPassword(_password);
        ftp.getAdvancedFTPSettings().setConnectMode(FTPConnectMode.PASV);
}

...
ftp.connect();

someLogFunction("step1");

ftp.downloadFile(localFile, targetFile); 

someLogFunction("step2");

ftp.disconnect();

someLogFunction("step3");
```

...

ftp.downloadFile() is OK, because step2 is logged but step3 is not. Log of exceptions contains:

com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.ControlChannelIOException: Connection reset
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.readLine(FTPControlSocket.java:1014)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.readReply(FTPControlSocket.java:1049)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.sendCommand(FTPControlSocket.java:973)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.quit(FTPClient.java:3947)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.disconnect(FileTransferClient.java:1017)
    at ftp.FTPdownload.downloadFile(FTPdownload.java:47)

**Can you help me?** It will be propably some incorrect server setting.

Comment: Please show the code... Especially the `downloadFile` method from class `FTPdownload`.

Comment: `downloadFile()` is method from class `FileTransferClient` - https://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpj/doc/api/com/enterprisedt/net/ftp/FileTransferClient.html#disconnect%28%29

Comment: For a start, I'd enclose `disconnect` call in try/catch. Then log, what the error actually is. Maybe it is a bug in the lib and you can ignore the exception or indeed the server is misbehaving, which in turn could be solved by ignoring (but logging!) the exception. To me it looks like the connection is closed prematurely by the server.

Comment: Fildor, change your comment to Answer - so I can accept it. Ingoring exception is a pretty good solution (and working :D). Thanks

Comment: I asked for the _code_, not a javadoc link. But since you have your answer...